# Access $parent's $parent in knockout view - nesting context

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

**Updated for brevity**

How can I reference the $parents' $parent in nested Knockout foreach / with bindings?

Example -

```
    <!-- ko foreach: grandParent -->
        <tr>
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.parents --> // <-- Doesn't work
                <!-- ko foreach: children -->
                    <td data-bind="if: favToy().name == $parent.$parent.favToy().name">
                        <span data-bind="text: favToy().name"></span>
                    </td>
                <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
```

**Original**

Sorry for the confusing question but I am trying to reach a second level parent's value to check against a value in the current context (like below) to only show a span if it matches a $parent's $parent's value (ugh!)

```
    <!-- ko foreach: grandParent -->
        <tr>
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.parents -->
                <!-- ko foreach: children -->
                    <td data-bind="if: favToy().name == $parent.$parent.favToy().name">
                        <span data-bind="text: favToy().name"></span>
                    </td>
                <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
```

It would be easier to do it this way but from what I have read this is not possible or I am doing it wrong :)

```
    <!-- ko foreach: grandParent -->
        <tr>
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.parents -->
                <!-- ko foreach: children ? favToy().name == $parent.$parent.favToy().name -->
                    <td  data-bind="text: favToy().name"></td>
                <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your question, what is not working? What is your problem: is the syntax of `$parent.$parent` or that you must use `span` because you cannot merge the `foreach` and the `if`?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Use the `$parents` array, the grandparent would be `$parents[1]`. You may also be able to use `$root` if the `grandParent` object in your example is the topmost parent.

From the [docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html):

> **$parents**
>
> This is an array representing all of the parent view models:
>
> $parents[0] is the view model from the parent context (i.e., it’s the
>   same as $parent)
>
> $parents[1] is the view model from the grandparent context
>
> $parents[2] is the view model from the great-grandparent context
>
> … and so on.
>
> **$root**
>
> This is the main view model object in the root context, i.e., the
>   topmost parent context. It’s usually the object that was passed to
>   ko.applyBindings. It is equivalent to $parents[$parents.length - 1].

Comment: For some reason `$parent.$parent` did not work for me, this solution however worked fine, and it's shorter too!

Answer (score 10):

You can use `$parentContext.$parent`.

`$parentContext` provide many useful properties such as (`$data`, `$parent`, `$index`, ...)

Comment: In my cases, I had a foreach inside of a foreach and wanted to access the $index of the 1st one from the 2nd loop.  $parentContext.$index() worked!

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier to use the noChildContext setting like this:

> Using “as” without creating a child context
>
> The default behavior of the as option is to add a name for the current item while still also binding the contents to the item. But you may prefer keep the context unchanged and only set the name of the current item. This latter behavior will probably be the default in a future version of Knockout. To turn it on for a specific binding, set the noChildContext option to true. When this option is used along with as, all access to the array items must be through the given name, and $data will remain set to the outer viewmodel. For example:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: categories, as: 'category', noChildContext: true }">
    <li>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: { data: category.items, as: 'item', noChildContext: true }">
            <li>
                <span data-bind="text: category.name"></span>:
                <span data-bind="text: item"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[Read more here](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)