# knockoutjs binding to $parent issue

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am binding my view to  the following viewmodel. I am sharing only relevant parts of it though.

```
self.store_data = {
        id: ko.observable(-1),
        business_name: ko.observable(''),
        company_number: ko.observable(''),
        trading_number: ko.observable(''),
        address: ko.observable(''),
        postcode: ko.observable(''),
        phone_number: ko.observable(''),
        opening_hours: ko.observable(''),
        closing_hours: ko.observable(''),
        is_bank_holiday: ko.observable(false),
        business_photo: ko.observable(null),
        business_photo_type: ko.observable('jpeg'),
        lat: ko.observable(''),
        lng: ko.observable(''),
        is_premium: ko.observable(false),
        is_closed: ko.observable(0),
        catalog : ko.observable(), //selected catalog
        timings_calendar : {
                'mon': {
                    holiday: ko.observable(false),
                    timings: ko.observableArray([
                        new self.Timings('9:00:00', '01:00:00'),
                        new self.Timings('02:00:00', '06:00:00')
                    ])
                },
                    'tue': {
                    holiday: ko.observable(false),
                    timings: ko.observableArray([
                        new self.Timings('9:00:00', '01:00:00'),
                        new self.Timings('02:00:00', '06:00:00')
                    ])
                },...
```

and here is the view where `data-bind="checked: $parent.$parent.holiday() == false"`  is not getting binded with this error "TypeError: Cannot call method 'holiday' of undefined". What is the issue? please help.

```
<!-- ko foreach: store_data.timings_calendar.mon.timings -->
                            <div class="ui-block-a" style="width: 30%;">
                                <!-- ko if: $index() === 0 -->
                                <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $parent.$parent.holiday() == false" id="monday-timings-checkbox" data-mini="true" /> <label for="monday-timings-checkbox">Mon</label>
                                <!-- /ko -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="ui-block-b" style="width: 30%;">
                                <select  data-mini="true" data-bind="options: $root.timeModel.timings, optionsText: 'text', optionsValue: 'value', value: $data.opening_hours "></select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ui-block-c" style="width: 30%;">
                                <select  data-mini="true" data-bind="options: $root.timeModel.timings, optionsText: 'text', optionsValue: 'value', value: $data.closing_hours "></select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ui-block-c" style="width: 10%;">
                                <!-- ko if: $data.opening_hours() != '' && $data.closing_hours() != '' && $index() != $parent.length -1 -->
                                    <button data-mini="true" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="a"></button>
                                <!-- /ko -->

                                <!-- ko ifnot: $data.opening_hours() != '' && $data.closing_hours() != '' && $index() != $parent.length -1 -->
                                    <button data-mini="true" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="b"></button>
                                <!-- /ko -->


                            </div>

                            <!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: it's better to just paster your code and format it rather than upload images of the code. it's easier for people to edit and post answers that way. Better still create a JSFiddle demonstrating the issue.

Comment: text added for your convenience.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access $parent's $parent in knockout view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17069381/access-parents-parent-in-knockout-view)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `$parent.$parent` you should use  `$parents[1]` instead.

See the [docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html).

Comment: actually, it's $parents[1]. But that is stated in the docs you linked anyway :)

Comment: $parents[1] looks fine, but it gives the same error.

Anyway, I'm able to do it with `data-bind="checked: $root.store_data.timings_calendar.mon.holiday() == false"`

Comment: Just a side note, to have this level of coupling to the structure of the viewmodels are bad. Its better if you have some kind of event bus that can publish when holiday changes

Comment: Also using $root is even more fragile than $parent(s) since its absolute it will break if you choose to insert a new viewmodel at the top